# prove if $[A,B] = 0$ and $Af=\lambda f$ then $f$ is an eigenfunction both for $A$ and $B$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let commutator of two operators A, B be $[A, B] = AB - BA$

prove: if $[A,B] = 0$ and $Af=\lambda f$ and there are no repeated eigenvalues, then $f$ is eigenfunction both for $A$ and $B$

My book gives the following proof:

$$ABf - BAf = 0$$
$$ABf - B\lambda f = 0$$
$$A(Bf) = \lambda (Bf)$$
thus $Bf$ is an eigenfunction of $A$,
so
$$Bf=\mu f$$
for some $\mu$ since by assumption $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue. Thus $f$ is an eigenfunction for both $A$ and $B$

I can't understand: how $Bf$ is an eigenfunction of $A$ implies $Bf=\mu f$?

As $A(Bf) = \lambda (Bf)$ makes $(Bf)$ an eigenfunction of $A$ **with eigenvalue $\lambda$**

So it turns out that $\lambda$ is the same for both $f$ and $Bf$, which contradicts the assumption "there are no repeated eigenvalues"

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $f$ and $Bf$ are both eigenfunctions with the same eigenvalue is not a contradiction. It just means that they are scalar multiples of each other. And that's the point: $Bf$ is some scalar multiple of $f$, though the scalar is not necessarily $\lambda$. And thus $f$ is an eigenfunction of $B$.

Comment: Yep, now I see the logic: $\lambda$ works only for $f$ and $A$. But the fact it works for $A(Bf) = \lambda (Bf)$ tells us that we have to look for an explanation why this is true. And it may be true only if $Bf = \mu f$ ($A(\mu f) = \lambda (\mu f)$, $\mu$ cancels, we're happy). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $AB= BA$ and $ Af=\lambda f$ for some $\lambda$. Then
$$ A(Bf ) = BAf = B(\lambda f) = \lambda Bf.$$
This means that the eigenspace $S_A(\lambda)$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is invariant under the action of $B$, i.e.
$$ B S_A(\lambda) \subset S_A(\lambda). $$
If $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues, then all its eigenspaces are of dimension 1, i.e.
$$B f =\mu f$$
for some $\mu$.

Comment: wow. I even wasn't thinking about eigenspace. Now I'll check it out. As of now, I can't comprehend your answer immediately, but will get back to it as soon as I read about eigenspaces. Thank you for the hint!